# Android - RecyclerView repeats programmatically added imageviews

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my project I need to add a different amount of `ImageView` per row depending on the response from a webservice, I manage to do that but when I scroll on the `recyclerView` the  `ImageView` from the rows repeats itself.

the idea of my app is to be able to create and share combos(set of inputs for videogames). Here's my code for the adapter.

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == TYPE_COMBO) {
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent,false);
        ComboViewHolder comboViewHolder = new ComboViewHolder(row);
        return comboViewHolder;
    } else {
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.progress_footer, parent, false);
        FooterViewHolder footerViewHolder = new FooterViewHolder(row);
        return footerViewHolder;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof ComboViewHolder) {
        ComboViewHolder comboViewHolder = (ComboViewHolder) holder;
        ComboImp comboImp = (ComboImp) data.get(position);
        ComboConverter comboConverter = new ComboConverter();
        comboConverter.convertToPS4(comboImp.getCombo());
        LinearLayout LinearLayout = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams imageViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int[] comboItems = comboConverter.convertToPS4(comboImp.getCombo());
        PairingFunction pairingFunction = new PairingFunction();
        for (int i = 0; i < comboItems.length; i++) {
            int id = pairingFunction.pair(i + 1, position + 1);
            comboViewHolder.imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            comboViewHolder.imageView.setId(id);
            comboViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(0);
            comboViewHolder.imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);
            comboViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(comboConverter.getPs4Picture(Control.getByCode(comboItems[i])));
            linearLayout.addView(comboViewHolder.imageView);
        }
        comboViewHolder.linearLayout.addView(linearLayout);
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}


public static class ComboViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView combo,postDate;
    private View circleView;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private ImageView imageView;
    public ComboViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.LinearRow);
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ps4_square_30x30);
            }
        });
    }
    public TextView getCombo() {
        return combo;
    }
    public TextView getPostDate() {
        return postDate;
    }

    public View getCircleView() {
        return circleView;
    }

    public View getImageView() {
        return imageView;
    }
    public LinearLayout getLinearLayout(){return linearLayout;}
}
```

as for the XML file is a simple LinearLayout with nothing in it.

I used a pairing function to set a unique ID for each  `ImageView` created, it's not perfect(with enough row and  `ImageView` the Integer will max out) but will work for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a line like this in you onBindViewHolder() method at the top

```
comboViewHolder.linearLayout.removeAllViews();
```

Comment: glad it helps @AlexanderJimenez. Please upvote answer. Thanks

Comment: sorry, i tried, but my reputation isn't high enough(less than 15) so that my votes reflects on the score

Answer (score 0):

Programmatically added views and Recycler/Grid/List views are a bad combo.  THey really screw with recycling, because you're adding them to a view, but they don't get removed when recycled.  To make them work, each time onBindViewHolder is called you MUST remove all programmatically added views and readd them.  This is counter to the very idea of view recycling and very expensive in terms of time, so its really not suggested.

The only other idea is to write your own recycling logic into the layout so you recycle the added views by hand from a separate recycling pool.  Which is doable, but a real pain in the neck.

TO be a nice guy-  here's my LinearLayout replacement that does in recycler recycling.  Its still not 100% efficient (it would need to share between rows to be even better, I'll make it do that some day), but it will at least minimize the performance hit of adding new rows to the recycled layout.  Feel free to adapt it to work with a RelativeLayout like it looks you need:

```
public class RecycledLinearLayout extends LinearLayout {

    public interface RecyledLinearLayoutAdapter<ItemType, HolderType> {
        View createView(ViewGroup parent);
        HolderType createHolder(View view);
        void assignToView(View view, HolderType holder, ItemType item);
    }

    private List<View> mRecycledTaskViews;
    private List<Object> mRecycledTaskHolders;
    private RecyledLinearLayoutAdapter mAdapter;

    public RecycledLinearLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null, 0);
    }

    public RecycledLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RecycledLinearLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        mRecycledTaskViews = new ArrayList<>();
        mRecycledTaskHolders = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void setAdapter(RecyledLinearLayoutAdapter adapter) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    public void setItems(List items) {
        removeAllViews();
        if(mAdapter == null || items == null) {
            return;
        }
        for(int i = mRecycledTaskViews.size(); i < items.size(); i++) {
            View view = mAdapter.createView(this);
            mRecycledTaskViews.add(view);
            mRecycledTaskHolders.add(mAdapter.createHolder(view));
        }
        for(int i=0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            Object item = items.get(i);
            View currentView = mRecycledTaskViews.get(i);
            Object currentHolder = mRecycledTaskHolders.get(i);
            mAdapter.assignToView(currentView, currentHolder, item);
            addView(currentView);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
   for (int i = 0; i < comboItems.length; i++) {
              int id = pairingFunction.pair(i + 1, position + 1);
              ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
              imageView.setId(id);
              imageView.setImageResource(0);
              imageView.setLayoutParams(imageViewParams);
              imageView.setImageResource(comboConverter.getPs4Picture(Control.getByCode(comboItems[i])));
              relativeLayout.addView(imageView);
    }
```